# Friction in mass energy equivalence

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, friction, mass-energy

[image]

Here it has been pointed out that as a body receives energy $E$, it's mass increases by well by an amount $\frac{E}{c^2}$. In the question given, friction has been considered. Now we know work done on a body is it's energy and friction does negative work on the body since force and displacement are in opposite direction,so that *in some sense* takes away energy from the body since *negative means subtraction*. Then how does heat energy get produced in the body?Is it possible to explain this heat energy mathematically?

Comment: I expect you would do better if you tried to answer one question at a time. For example, you seem to be tripping over a negative sign, but also wanting to know about the definition of mass in special relativity. Maybe focus?

Comment: Actually my main question is,how does friction produce heat energy in the body whereas it does negative work on body(i.e takes away energy from body)